# Flutter localization and sdk may be incompatible

Tags: android, flutter, dictionary, localization, yaml

Here is my Error
Pub get givig this error[image: Help me to resolve please I'm new on flutter]

Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application...

Because google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 depends on intl >=0.16.0 <=0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because markets depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 4):

You can override the dependency using **dependency_overrides** in your **pubspec.yaml**

Example

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.16.0
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
//your other dependance
```